# Complexity of Document.getElementsByClassName()?

Tags: javascript, html, css, time-complexity, runtime

Document.getElementbyID() is a O(1) operation but what is the complexity of retrieving elements by class. Does it get all the DOM elements and then match it to the queried class or does it internally have a map?

Comment: This would be implementation dependant. It's possible that it's traversing every single node, or it might be caching them. Browsers are free to optimise the algorithm as they see fit, as long as it works.

Answer (score 1):

According to Mozilla Web Docs:

```
When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node.
```

This makes me believe that the complexity would be O(n).